# By any chance, can we visualize what all goes to stack and what all goes to heap in a process (may be c#)?

Tags: c#, debugging, stack-trace, heap-memory, diagnostic-tools

I started exploring the Clrmd for visualizing what all variables that goes to stack and heap, and ended up with some set of (>1000) objects in the heap out of which majority of are of string type, which are not created by me in the process and a stacktrace that just gives the information about methods(stackframes )in each thread but not about the variables and other properties that are present in the method.

My questions are:

1. Why and how those number of string objects are created in heap ,even if i didnot use any strings in my program(c# code).
2. Is there any way to filter the heap objects such that only the objects used by the program (my c# code leaving behind the internally created objects by the program ) are displayed using clrmd or any other nuget package or a tool.
3. By any chance can i display the set of variables(local variables) that  are used in the methods using the stackframe  of the process(MY C# CODE) in another process.

Answer (score 0):

Dear Ganesh you can try Red-gate [ANTS Memory Profiler] to track the object on memory and filter them by any type ... follow the link below

[here](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/)

Comment: I just read about ants memory profiler but it couldnot answer my questions(1,2,3), anyway I will try it. Thankyou for your consideration.